# Data point on Y-Axis

Tags: xaml, windows-store-apps, winrt-xaml, winrt-xaml-toolkit

I am using ***WinRTXamlToolkit*** and creating a *LineChart*. By default the chart does not allow data points ON the axes. But I want to populate the starting data point/coordinate on the y-axis e.g. (0, 20).

How can this be done? I have yet to discover a way. Any suggestion will be helpful.

Comment: I would start at the source. Grab the toolkit's solution and hit F5. Open the chart sample and hit Ctrl+Shift while pointing at different elements of the chart; explore the visual tree. I didn't write the original control, but I suspect you might need to specify a custom `IndependentAxis` for your `LineSeries`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer is posted in the comment above by Filip who made the library.